# Using radiobuttons in an experiment to edit parameter in main

Tags: anylogic

There is little guidance on how the radiobuttons work. Say I want to have radiobuttons in my experiment that will edit  myParameter in main.

The radiobuttons will have three options: A, B, C. 
If option A is selected I want myParameter to have value X.
If option B is selected I want myParameter to have value Y, etc.

How would I do this and what code do I need to write and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have a radio button on the experiment canvas with A,B,C as your options.  Create a function at the experiment level called getRadioValue to reason with the radio values and return what you want.

getRadioValue example:

```
if( radio.getValue() == 0 )
    return 10;
else if( radio.getValue() == 1 )
    return 20;
else
    return 30;
```

In the experiment properties, pass in getRadioValue() to the myParameter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the "Action" code in the radio button properties to set a variable in your experiment (that you then feed through to a param on Main).

You can use this code to set the variable each time the radio button is changed:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this different approach, Benjamin.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun if you want to use switch instead of the if statement (using Amy's example), the getRadioValue function would be:

```
switch(radio.getValue()){
    case 0:
        return 10;
    case 1:
        return 20;
    default:
        return 30;
}
```

and using Benjamin's example

```
switch(value){
    case 0:
        variable=12;
        break;
    case 1:
        variable=21;
}
```